# DynamoDB Sorting order on duplicate Global Secondary Indexes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I was trying to get information on how DynamoDB resolves sorting order for global secondary index when two items' hash key - range key values are the same. Does it refer to the original table's sort key?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order appears to be undefined.

> In a DynamoDB table, each key value must be unique. However, the key values in a global secondary index do not need to be unique.
>
> [...]
>
> Only the items with the specified key values appear in the response; within that set of data, the items are in no particular order.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

Answer (score 0):

Global Secondary Index(GSI) sort order is determined by a `trailinghashkey` which is made up of the hash of your base tables partition key, and sort key. This means that the sort order is deterministic but impossible to predict without knowing the internal hash function.

This is also the reason why a GSI projection always includes Keys, regardless if your intentionally project them or not.